# Library to convert image files to PDF in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: pdf, c#, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app.

I have to convert images files to PDF.

Which libraries are available freely that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way. I am using Component One Library(third party).

If Anyone wants, here is the answer:

```
using C1.Phone.Pdf;
using C1.Phone.PdfViewer;

C1PdfDocument pdf = new C1PdfDocument(PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated);
pdf.Landscape = true;
var rc = new System.Windows.Rect(20,30,300,200);
pdf.DrawImage(wbitmp, rc);

var fillingName = "Test.pdf";
var gettingFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var loadingFinalStream = gettingFile.CreateFile(fillingName))
{
    pdf.Save(loadingFinalStream);
}
```